# Oracle 12 C missing Sample schemas

Tags: schema, sample, oracle12c

I installed Oracle 12C, now I am trying to install sample schemas but some of the scipts for sample schema are missing.

Where can I download the scipts for sample schemas of ORACLE 12 C

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What I found is , Oracle 12C is not stable, it's missing some files.. I cleaned my system and installed Oracle 11G and I get all the required files. 12C is kind a new, may be it needs more time to get stabilized. It's missing major schema like HR etc...